# How to code google analytics for mobile apps?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to android programming and I assume that I've completely prepared my app to use google-analytics including setting up the necessary plugins, dependencies, configurations , etc... according to [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/).
but for coding my activities I'm quite confused and i couldn't find straightforward instructions to code my activities in order to use the minimum features of google analytics (like merely knowing the number of page visits and user counts).thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was quite simple.. all i needed was modifying the oncreate method  like below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Tracker mTracker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
    mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
    mTracker.setScreenName("Home");
    mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
```

and a few adjustments in the manifest.